# Move `.devcontainers/` to outside the repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm frequently working in repositories I do not own (typically open source things). I often want to run dev containers in VS Code as part of my workflow. However, VS Code creates a `.devcontainers/` directory for the configuration. For my own repos, this would be a good thing. I would like to have those config files checked into Git so I can track them and share them with other contributors. But for repos I do not own, it's not great. I'd much rather have them somewhere else, like in my home directory.

Is it possible to get VS Code to keep the `.devcontainers/` directory outside of the repo I have opened in the dev container?

Comment: I'd like to understand what you mean when you say `you do not own`. _Every_ local repo that you have..... you _own_ them.... they are _yours_ to do as you please... nothing that you do on them will affect anybody else's repos.

Comment: I think lindhe is talking about creating your own GitHub repository vs. contributing to someone else's repo

Comment: @eftshift0: Yeah, what @nate-thegrate says. I mean that I should not commit the `.devcontainers/` dir to the repo since it's a repo I am not the maintainer of, so that dir just hangs around like a nobody in my Git tree. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily there's a super convenient solution: add `.devcontainers/` to the [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file.

(If there isn't already a .gitignore file in the repo, you would need to create one.)

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for, but it is the solution I am going for. More specifically: I _cannot_ add it to the `.gitignore` for the repo, since that too would be an unasked for contribution to someone else's repo. But what I have done is to add it to my [global `.gitignore`](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_core_excludesfile) file (in my case [`~/.gitignore_global`](https://github.com/lindhe/dotfiles/blob/0800d26851970672bbf7716a60faa8caf1ac0028/.gitignore_global#L39).

Comment: This will make it so that it's ignored by default for me, but if a repo I clone already have a `.devcontainers/` committed, it will of course stay tracked.  And if I would like to commit it some time, I'll just have to do `git add -f .devcontainers/`.